# how to override configuration of elasticSearch in liferay 7.2

Tags: jsp, elasticsearch, overriding, liferay-7

i think i need to override the default behaviour of elastic search in liferay to

- Exclude images (png,jpg...etc etc) from search results.
- Be sure that the search results displayed contain ONLY the entirely keyword searched (example: i search "como" -> i only want to get the entire word "como" and not "comodo" or "comasco" or "consiglio").
- When i index a pdf document in it there are some html entities (example: `&nbsp;`) and those break the search results layout page. How to delete html entites from the documents?

I think i have to override the default json of elastich search, but i don't know what json/yml and how.

I use liferay 7.2

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize Elasticsearch mappings, you can go to:

- Control Panel → Configuration → System Settings → Platform.
- Find the Elasticsearch entry (scroll down and browse to it or use the search box) and click the Actions icon, then Edit.
- Setup your custom mappings in "Overriding Type Mappings" section.

You should copy current JSON mappings and customize them.

You have more information here:

- https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/deploy/-/knowledge_base/d/advanced-configuration-of-the-liferay-elasticsearch-connector#overriding-type-mappings